# Make 4 cells with divisor

Tags: html, css

How can I make these divisors of a simplest box. I have this simple box html and css.
HTML code is:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

and CSS code of box is:

```
#box{

    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px; /* IE10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100, #d6d6d6)); /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* W3C Markup */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);

}
```

OK. Let's go to divisor... how can i do them? Image linked is here:

[image: example]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are either going to need to insert a background image with the lines on the image or create sections within the box and styling the box based on where it is located in the main box.

```css
#box{
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 5px; /* IE10+ */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100, #d6d6d6)); /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%); /* W3C Markup */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
    font-size:0px;
}
.section{
  width:49.25%;
  height:49%;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  display:inline-block;
}

#top-left{
  border-bottom:5px solid white;
  border-right:5px solid white;
}

#top-right{
  border-bottom:5px solid white;
}

#bottom-left{
  border-right:5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="section" id="top-left"></div>
  <div class="section" id="top-right"></div>
  <div class="section" id="bottom-left"></div>
  <div class="section" id="bottom-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok. But they don't touch  the box edges..if you can see...and the divisors are a gradient too... thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of pseudo-elements overlaid on top might work:

```css
body {
  background: #c0ffee;
}
#box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE10+ */
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  /* Mozilla Firefox */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  /* Opera */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #FFFFFF), color-stop(100, #d6d6d6));
  /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  /* W3C Markup */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 0%, #d6d6d6 100%);
  position: relative;
}
#box::before,
#box::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
#box::before {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
  height: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, lightgrey);
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#box::after {
  width: 4px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, white, lightgrey);
  border-radius: 3px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: So you want them to or not? They're sized to be 100% but you can change that to 96% (or whatever) and then adjust the positioning.to suit your needs.